# Microcontroller Core Frequency vs Crystal Frequency

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, current, oscillator, crystal

If I use an external 8MHz crystal connector to a microcontroller, but the core can run at a higher frequency. Like what factor decides that the core should run at a higher frequency ?

And whether increasing the crystal frequency value, say from 8MHz to 40MHz part, increases the load capacitance value that is connected to the crystal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost any modern microcontroller has an oscillator control block, which typically comprises one or more internal oscillators, pins for external (crystal or other), oscillators, phased locked loops (to multiply the basic osciallator frequency), dividers, and lots of logic to control all this stuff. The end result is that you can generally configure not only the core frequency, but the frequencies used by subsystems such as IO, and memory.

To see the specific features available, you need to study the datasheet. There are also often software configuration tools available (like STM CubeMX).

And no, you don't have to mess with the crystal caps depending on config - the crystal will be internally buffered. Just use the suggested values in the datasheet.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But what determines that the core should run at a higher frequency ?

Comment: quite simply, your choice. Typically determined by how much processing power your application needs and supply current. In many cases the default setup is fine, but always worth reviewing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just a follow up question. Do you know what would be the voltage level at the input pins of the crystal (EXTAL, XTAL), say if my Micro is powered by 5V? Would it be the same 5V sine wave?

Comment: no. You typically see something vaguely sinuosoidal and at less than 5V pk-pk. But because the crystal circuit is so sensitive to capacitance, almost any contact with a scope probe (typically a few tens of pF) might affect operation or even screw it up. Really the signal at the pins of of crystal must be buffered by a gate, and you look at the output of that to see a logic level clock signal.

Answer (score 2):

The requirements of the application decide what should be the MCU core or crystal frequency.

If you need something special, like use an AVR and have UART with baud rate of 115200, it can't be done with a 8 MHz crystal, but it can be done with 7.3728 MHz crystal.

If you use another MCU which has a PLL you can use 8 MHz crystal and let the core and UART run at high enough frequency to achieve divisors down to 115200 with good enough error margin. If you simply need raw processing power, you should run the MCU at highest possible frequency to use least time for what you need to do.

Crystal frequency has no relation to load capacitance. Crystals meant for series oscillation do not even have a rated load capacitance.
You can for example buy both 8 MHz and 20 MHz crystals with same 20pF load capacitance rating if you want, there is no relation.

It's just that due to oscillator in the MCU, a higher frequency crystal might need to be rated with lower load capacitance for stable operation. So not all crystals are compatible with all MCUs, you need to read MCU datasheets what kind of crystals are compatible with it.

The crystal frequency vs MCU frequency depends on what kind of PLL it has inside it. Most likely you can't use a 40 MHz crystal, so if you want some specific MCU frequency like 40MHz, you need to figure out which PLL settings to use and that determines what frequency crystals can be used. It can be achieved in multiple ways, e.g. 4 MHz with 10x multiplier, or 10 MHz with 4x multiplier.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just a follow up question. Do you know what would be the voltage level at the input pins of the crystal (EXTAL, XTAL), say if my Micro is powered by 5V? Would it be the same 5V sine wave?

Comment: No, it would not be a 5V sine wave. The level is what is said in the microcontroller datasheet. And you have not revealed which MCU you use, so you will get a generic "it depends" answer. Let me guess, 2SK something MCU?

Comment: Yes, it is S32K142